# Saving 2 PHPSESSID accessing computer using same IP address

Tags: php, apache, cookies, subdomain, wamp

Server is **WAMP**. I have 2 sugarcrm sites, one for production say, saved at **www/folder1** , other for development say saved at **www/folder2** . I am accessing them using IP address (say **66.102.0.0/folder1** and **66.102.0.0/folder2** ) . Browser saves 1 cookie (PHPSESSID) for both of them. If I login/logout to first site, it effects other site also. I can create subdomain at localhost like **folder1.localhost** and **folder2.localhost** but how IP based sub-domain is possible like, **folder1.66.102.0.0** and **folder2.66.102.0.0** (looks funny :) ) ?Or can I use different port for different folder, like **66.102.0.0:80** and **66.102.0.0:8080** ?Then will browser saved 2 cookies, if port is different on same ip address?**I can't change login/logout, it's sugarcrm not core php.** I can use different browsers but my boss is saying to make cookies separately. Or is there any browser Add-on that separates cookies based on folder?

Answer (score 0):

Call `session_set_cookie_params()` to restrict the cookie to a particular folder:

```
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($params['lifetime'], '/folder1');
session_start();
```

Comment: Thanks, Ok, I am trying but I wish I don't touch/change SUGARCRM core.

Comment: Anyway, this will change only php session path not browser phpsessionid. This thing is already done. Now I want browser side different cookie.

Comment: That's not correct. Cookies are associated with a path. So if the PHPSESSID cookie is assigned to /folder1, it will not be seen by /folder2, so it will start a new session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Creating subdomains should solve your problem. I do this all the time.

If you are opening your site as `66.102.0.0` then your session is based on that url which is causing all the problems.

**Note:** Directories mentioned here are windows wamp specific but as long as you find the appropriate files, this applies to Apache in all OS's.

**Step 1.** Uncomment this line in your `bin/apache/Apache*.*.*/conf/httpd.conf`

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**Step 2.** Make a virtual host entries in your `bin/apache/Apache*.*.*/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/folder1"
    ServerName folder1.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/folder1.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/folder1.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/folder2"
    ServerName folder2.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/folder2.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/folder2.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 3.** Restart wampserver / apache.

**Step 4.** Edit your hosts file. `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Add in the entries.

```
127.0.0.1 folder1.localhost # You probably want 66.102.0.0 over here instead of 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 folder2.localhost
```

Comment: Your hosts file is wrong, you can't have multiple lines with the same IP. Put all the aliases on the same line.

Comment: Well it seems to work. I've been doing it for ages. Never really read up on the official format though. You can also do what Barmar said. `127.0.0.1 name1 name2` etc.

Comment: How do I access them using ip address?

Comment: You can't access virtual hosts using IP addresses. Virtual hosting needs different names.

Comment: If you type an IP address into the browsers bar then you only get to ONE website. You cant visit 2 websites using one ip address. But two different urls lead to two different websites (even though they might be on the same ip address). You would need different ports if you want two websites on the same ip; but since you need to mention the port its practically two different names.

Comment: You can pick `folder1.66.102.0.0` as your name by the way. If that is what you were asking. It doesnt have to be `folder1.localhost`.